# Angular 14: <select> displays incorrect value when updating data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, input, ngmodel

I use `[ngModel]` to assign the currently selected option to a  dropdown menu, and when the page is loaded initially this works fine, but sometimes when updating the data while the page is still loaded, the dropdown displays an incorrect value, but the model itself is still correct.

```
<select *ngIf="effect.type == ruleEffects.ApplyTemplate" class="form-select"
    [disabled]="readOnly" [ngModel]="effect.impact"
    (ngModelChange)="updateImpact($event, j)">
<option *ngFor="let template of templates" [value]="template.TemplateName">
    {{template.TemplateName}}
</option>
</select>
```

Verifying `{{effect.impact}}` shows that the correct template is currently selected, but the dropdown box will still list an incorrect value.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What do you have inside updateImpact($event, j)?

Comment: @Ale_Bianco Ah I should have removed that, it is not called in this situation, and the problem persists with it removed

Comment: What do you need inside effect.impact? Template or TemplateName?

Comment: @Ale_Bianco just TemplateName in this instance

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this?

```
<select *ngIf="effect.type == ruleEffects.ApplyTemplate" class="form-select"
    [disabled]="readOnly" [(ngModel)]="effect.impact">
    <option *ngFor="let template of templates" [value]="template.TemplateName">
       {{template.TemplateName}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the problem still persists, but I did realise that effect.impact is an 'any' type, while TemplateName is a string (and template is not inside effect.impact), I don't know if that impacts anything

Comment: This is an example of your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vdbbv7?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: My code works just like that example up until the template data is changed in the state, which is when the incorrect behaviour begins

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using [ngValue] instead of [value]?

```
    <select *ngIf="effect.type == ruleEffects.ApplyTemplate" class="form-select"
        [disabled]="readOnly" [(ngModel)]="effect.impact">
        <option *ngFor="let template of templates" [ngValue]="template.TemplateName">
           {{template.TemplateName}}
        </option>
    </select>
```